# Null pointer exception when setting adapter to listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have a list view with my custom adapter. My code was working good but I deployed it to the real device it start crashing. below line is a complete code I am getting so far.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

getting this error on exactly this line

> mlistView.setAdapter(myAdapterObj);

**what I have done so far.**

Here is the complete code of my adapter 
DbContentAdapter.java     // its my adapter class

```
public class DbContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyCustomData> {
Typeface tf;


public DbContentAdapter(Context context, List<MyCustomData> contentsItemss) {
    super(context, 0, contentsItemss);
    tf = Typefaces.get(context,"nastaleeqnumaregular");

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    MyCustomData ContentsItems = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_list_items, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContentNum);
    TextView tvUrduName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUrduName);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_contents);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvUrduName.setTypeface(tf);
    //tvName.setTypeface(tf);
    tvName.setText(ContentsItems.getTopicName());
    tvUrduName.setText(ContentsItems.getTopicUrduName());

    tvNum.setText(ContentsItems.getId()+"");
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_next_icon);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}}
```

I am sharing only my adapter code as I believe there is some thing mishandle here. In activity I tried tracking code in that but it seems just fine.

I have tried using Asynctask but all other things are same and the error are same with or with out using asynctask.

Update 1:  this is how I am creating my adapter.

```
        listUrduScienceEncyclopedia = customDbHelper.getDBData();
        contentAdapter = new DbContentAdapter(DbContentsActivity.this, listUrduScienceEncyclopedia);

    if(contentAdapter!=null) {
                    mlistView.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
                }
```

Please help me understand this error.

Comment: Please post other method of your adapter. Also post full logcat error not just one line of it.

Comment: this is my whole class dude for adapter

Comment: where are you find lmlistView using findViewById ?

Comment: We need to see the code where you are creating the adapter.

Comment: let me update ..............

Comment: `listUrduScienceEncyclopedia` must be null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your listUrduScienceEncyclopedia that you are passing to the adapter is null. Check that.

Comment: i am checking it also with condition but it is not working

Comment: Please show code for where you are initialising the adapter.

Comment: Check if listUrduScienceEncyclopedia is null and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this. I use to create a constructor while making the custom adapter. And also you have passed 0 instead of id for layout (ie,`super(context, 0, contentsItemss`). Correct me if I am wrong

```
public class DbContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyCustomData> {
Typeface tf;
List list ;
Activity context;


public DbContentAdapter(Context context, List<MyCustomData> contentsItemss) {
super(context, R.layout.content_list_items, contentsItemss);
this.list = contentsItemss;
this.context = context;
tf = Typefaces.get(context,"nastaleeqnumaregular");

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation with your answer as to *how* and *why* this should help the OP. It is much better for everyone than simply pasting code.

Comment: Actually I was making a custom adapter. That's why I did post it in a hurry and left. Sorry